# SQL Server Backup for UNC path

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using query to make sql server backup in my system. It is working fine when I gave full path (including drive letter) but when I use UNC path, it is not working. So tell me how to make it work for UNC path?

Comment: Define "not working"? Any error? What is it? Does your domain firewall allow network connections from your server to its target? Depending on the situation, you may have to fix the permissions/sharing on the destination folder, or in some cases end up mounting a drive (in SOME cases) first.. More info would help :)

Comment: How to find out - Domain firewall allow network connections from your server to its target? and Tell me how to set the firewall to make it work? Anything need to set in SQL Server Configuration section.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a "Backup device" connected to the UNC path. And do your backups on this device. It definitely works.
So, backups to the UNC path works as well too, BUT - check the path's permissions for account under which sql server is running

Comment: When backing up to a UNC path, what matters is the permissions granted for that path to the account that the "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" service is running under on the database server itself.  The "LocalService" account won't have access to UNC paths.  But you can keep the SQL Server Agent service running under LocalService.